# Replace character vector elements in dataframe with values in R

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a dataframe with a many character columns in it. The columns contains empty textstrings and textstrings. I would like to replace all the empty textstrings inside the dataframe with a 0 and the elements containing strings with number 1.
Can't figure out how to do it though....

simple example to illustrate :

```
> df
       A   B  C
1: asdad       
2:           sd
3:    as  sd sd
4: daasd  sd   
5:        sd   
6:           sd
7:    ds sds   
8:   asd       
9:        sd sd

> str(df)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: chr  "asdad" "" "as" "daasd" ...
 $ B: chr  "" "" "sd" "sd" ...
 $ C: chr  "" "sd" "sd" "" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

wanted :

```
> df
   A B C
1: 1 0 0
2: 0 0 1
3: 1 1 1
4: 1 1 0
5: 0 1 0
6: 0 0 1
7: 1 1 0
8: 1 0 0
9: 0 1 1

str(df)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
 $ B: int  0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
 $ C: int  0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple vectorized solution

```
(df != "") + 0
#    A B C
# 1: 1 0 0
# 2: 0 0 1
# 3: 1 1 1
# 4: 1 1 0
# 5: 0 1 0
# 6: 0 0 1
# 7: 0 1 1
# 8: 1 0 0
# 9: 0 1 1
```

If you have a `data.table` object add `as.data.table` as in

```
as.data.table((df != "") + 0)
```

---

**Some explanations**

When you do `df != ""`, R is basically comparing each value in `df` to `""` (blank) and returning a logical matrix with `TRUE` and `FALSE` indicating for each value if it is equals to `""` or not. when added `+ 0`, the logical values are converted to `1` and `0`.

---

**Edit:**

If you have a data.table object and you want to update it by reference you could do

```
df[, names(df) := lapply(.SD, function(x) (!x %in% c("", " ")) + 0)]
```

Comment: worked great on the example, however not on my original dataset. A lot of 1 where there should not be any. Hmmm, maybe there are some blankspaces or something in the dataset. Any ideas for fixing this

Comment: Well, I can't tell without the real data, sorry.

Comment: Tried to look at subset of it in excel and there were blankspaces in the dataset..any tips

Comment: Maybe `((df != "") & (df != " ")) + 0`?

Comment: Great, thank you!! That's it, I have got to learn this magic trick, any tips

Comment: There is no magic really. Added explanations to the answer. Try just running `df != ""` and see what you''ll get.

Comment: See my edit, I've added an option to update by reference if you have a data.table object. That could be more convenient for you